Function pickle is giving me this error, what is wrong?
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import os
import pickle
if not os.path.exists('bestEstimatorRF.pkl'):
randomForestModel = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, oob_score = True) 

paramsRF = { 
    'n_estimators': [50, 200, 700],
    'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']
}

randomForestGS = GridSearchCV(estimator=randomForestModel, 
                param_grid=paramsRF, 
                verbose=1, 
                scoring='accuracy')

randomForestGS.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(randomForestGS.best_score_)
print(randomForestGS.best_params_)
print(randomForestGS.best_estimator_)

with open('bestEstimatorRF.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(randomForestGS.best_estimator_, f)

# Updates randomForestModel to the best estimator to standardize it according to the pickle load
randomForestModel = randomForestGS.best_estimator_

else:
with open('bestEstimatorRF.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    randomForestModel = pickle.load(f)

print(randomForestModel)
randomForestModel.score(X_train, y_train)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [195], in <cell line: 5>()
31 else:
33     with open('bestEstimatorRF.pkl', 'rb') as f:
---> 34         randomForestModel = pickle.load(f)
36 print(randomForestModel)
38 randomForestModel.score(X_train, y_train)
File sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx:653, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.setstate()
File sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx:1340, in sklearn.tree._tree._check_node_ndarray()
ValueError: node array from the pickle has an incompatible dtype:

expected: [('left_child', '<i8'), ('right_child', '<i8'), ('feature', '<i8'), ('threshold', '<f8'), ('impurity', '<f8'), ('n_node_samples', '<i8'), ('weighted_n_node_samples', '<f8')]
got     : {'names':['left_child','right_child','feature','threshold','impurity','n_node_samples','weighted_n_node_samples','missing_go_to_left'], 'formats':['<i8','<i8','<i8','<f8','<f8','<i8','<f8','u1'], 'offsets':[0,8,16,24,32,40,48,56], 'itemsize':64}

I had already saved the model prediction, after running all again, this just showed up
